# WCF MessageContract complex type property not deserializing

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, messagecontract

I have to implement a service to handle this SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:serv="http://www.company.com/Service">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <serv:ServiceOperation xmlns="http://www.company.com/Service">
            <serv:operationParam>X</serv:operationParam>
            <serv:operationHeader>
                <serv:headerParamA>12345</serv:headerParamA>
                <serv:headerParamB>ABCD</serv:headerParamB>
                ...
```

The message contract currently looks like:

```
[MessageContract(
    WrapperName = nameof(ServiceOperation),
    WrapperNamespace = ServiceNamespace,
    IsWrapped = true)]
public class ServiceOperation
{

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "operationParam", Namespace = ServiceNamespace)]
    public string OperationParam { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "operationHeader", Namespace = ServiceNamespace)]
    public OperationHeader OperationHeader { get; set; }

    ...
```

The string property `operationParam` is parsed correctly by my service. But whatever I do, I cannot get the "complex type" `operationHeader` to work.

With the code above, properties on the `OperationHeader` are always null, regardless of `XmlType` and `XmlElement` declarations:

```
[XmlType]
public class OperationHeader
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string HeaderParamA { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried variations of the `OperationHeader` class with no attributes, `MessageBodyMember` attributes, decorating the XML type as anonymous. Still null on all members of the `OperationHeader` class.

Something very strange is that if I do this instead:

```
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "operationParam", Namespace = ServiceNamespace)]
    public string OperationParam { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "operationHeader", Namespace = ServiceNamespace)]
    public XmlElement OperationHeader { get; set; }
```

Then the XML element parsed is not the `operationHeader` itself, but the first *child* element from the XML; `headerParamA`.

Does anyone know what my classes should look like?

I've tried to do it exactly as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13750176/7724), but that only gives null for member properties on the complex type as well.

Or is the XML I'm sent broken somehow?

Comment: show definition of OperationHeader class

Comment: question updated @Maximus